# React map changes index number and breaks conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api

I'm using React map to render some slides in a facebook feed I have on my webpage. The function below takes the data I have collected from the Facebook Graph API and renders them into slides for the react-slick slider on my page.

The first slide should always be my  component, then the others should be a slide with an image and text. I have done this by saying if index=0 then render the  component.

It was working fine but recently it breaks and I have worked out this is because sometimes the first slide has an index of 1, not 0. I'm not sure why this is, shouldn't the first slide always have an index of 0?

```
renderSlides () {
  const { posts } = this.state
  const postsAvailable = posts.length > 0

  if (!postsAvailable) return null
  return posts.map((post, index) => {
    if (!post.message) return null
    return (
      <div key={post.id} ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}>
        {index === 0 && <SliderItem />}
        {index >= 1 && (
          <div className='item'>
            <img
              data-fb={post.full_picture}
            />
            <div className={`item-content slide-${post.id}`}>
              <p className='text'>{post.message}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

EDIT

Here is how I get the posts data from facebook

```
downloadFBAPI () {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.init({
        appId: appID,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v3.2'
      })
    }.bind(this);

    (function (d, s, id) {
      var js
      var fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id
      js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
    SuperAgent
      .get('APIcall')
      .accept('application/json')
      .use(legacyIESupport)
      .end(this.getData)
  }

  getData (err, res) {
    if (err || !res || !res.body) {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        err
      })
      return err
    } else {
      const result = res.body.data
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        posts: result
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: paste your posts object.

Answer (score 1):

> ...sometimes the first slide has an index of 1, not 0. I'm not sure why this is...

The **only** reason that will happen is if the array you call `map` on (`posts` in your example) is a *sparse* array with no entry at index 0. Example:

```js
const lower = [];
lower[1] = "one";
lower[2] = "two";
console.log(`'lower' has an entry at index 0? ${0 in lower}`);
console.log(`'lower' has an entry at index 1? ${1 in lower}`);
console.log(`'lower' has an entry at index 2? ${2 in lower}`);
console.log(`Mapping it:`);
const upper = lower.map((value, index) => {
    console.log(`index = ${index}`);
    return value.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(upper);
console.log(`'upper' has an entry at index 0? ${0 in upper}`);
console.log(`'upper' has an entry at index 1? ${1 in upper}`);
console.log(`'upper' has an entry at index 2? ${2 in upper}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

You can end up with a sparse array like that in at least three ways:

1. You created it that way (like `lower` above in the example above); or
2. *(Variation on #1.)* You created it by using `map` on an array that was sparse (like `upper` in the example); or
3. You used `delete` (or similar) to remove an entry from the array (`delete theArray[0];`)

The reason is that `map` only visits entries that exist in the array, it skips gaps in sparse arrays. Remember that, at a specification level, JavaScript's traditional arrays [aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)¹ (though they often are as an implementation optimization), which means you can have an array with `length` of `3` but only (for instance) two entries in it. That's what `lower` is above (also `upper`). Or you could have even more gaps:

```js
const a = [];
a[3] = "three";
a[5] = "five";
logArray("a", a);
const b = a.map((value, index) => {
    console.log(`index = ${index}`);
    return value.toUpperCase();
});
logArray("b", b);

function logArray(name, a) {
    console.log(`${name}'s length is ${a.length}`);
    for (let index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
        console.log(`${name} has entry at index ${index}? ${index in a}`);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

There, `a` and `b` don't have entries for indexes 0, 1, 2, or 4.

If you set `length` (or use `delete`), you can have gaps at the end, too.

---

¹ *(That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*

Comment: I define posts as a state like posts=[], should I do this differently? sometimes the index is 0 and sometimes it's 1, it's not always 1.

Comment: @user3005003 - `posts = []` is just fine (for creating an empty array). The issue is that after doing that, either you're not filling in the entry at index 0 (like the live examplea bove), or you're filling it in but removing it later.

Comment: Question: if you did as above, but started at `lower[5] = 'one'`, what would the index start at?

Comment: @ColinRicardo - 5, because `map` only visits entries that exist in the array. JavaScript's traditional arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) *(post on my very-anemic blog)*. If you do `const a = []; a[5] = "five";` you've created an array with `length` set to `6` (one higher than the highest index) with no entries at all at indexes 0-4 and an entry at index 5. Calling `map` on it would call `map`'s callback just once, with the value `"five"` and the index `5`.